# Node.js - simple example and EPERM error

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
var server = require('http').createServer(function(req, res){

});

server.listen(8080);
```

This simple example return error in console:

```
node node_server.js

node.js:201
    throw e; // process.nextTick error, or 'error' event on first tick
          ^
Error: listen EPERM
    at errnoException (net.js:670:11)
    at Array.0 (net.js:756:28)
    at EventEmitter._tickCallback (node.js:192:41)
```

What is going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Port was locked. Topic shutdown.